# In SELECT statement in Oracle how to add a column/variable based on the existence of a value in another table, efficiently?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, exists

I have two tables files and errors:

[image]

And

[image]

And I want to create a results set with dummy coded variables like this:

[image]

I can get it to work with CASE statements and EXISTS in a statement like this:

```
SELECT f.detail_id, 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM errors e WHERE f.detail_id = e.detail_id AND e.error_code = 400) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS error_400, 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM errors e WHERE f.detail_id = e.detail_id AND e.error_code = 405) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS error_405, 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM errors e WHERE f.detail_id = e.detail_id AND e.error_code = 410) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS error_410, 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM errors e WHERE f.detail_id = e.detail_id AND e.error_code = 392) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS error_392, 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM errors e WHERE f.detail_id = e.detail_id AND e.error_code = 401) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS error_401 
FROM files f
```

However, this code is very inefficient, slow, and long-running. How can I re-write this code to make it more efficient? How can I optimize it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This shouldn't be slow at all. Make sure you have an index on `errors (detail_id, error_code)`.

Comment: It is a little confusing that it looks like the detail_id is the primary key for the files table, both in your sample data and your query, but in that case it would be called id or file_id or the like, right? So, is the deteil_id unique in the files table?

Comment: Thorsten Kettner, the detail_id is the primary key in the files table and a foreign key in the errors table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner however the detail_id in the errors table has orphaned records such as rows 8 and 9 in my sample errors data table.

Comment: This is strange. How can there be a foreign key but still IDs that don't exist in the parent table? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right and its probably not an official foreign key with constraints. I used the term too loosely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't select the file number or name, you can get almost the same result by aggregating the errors table:

```
select
  detail_id,
  count(case when error_code = 400 then 1 end) as error_400,
  count(case when error_code = 405 then 1 end) as error_405,
  count(case when error_code = 410 then 1 end) as error_410,
  count(case when error_code = 392 then 1 end) as error_392,
  count(case when error_code = 401 then 1 end) as error_401
from errors
group by detail_id
order by detail_id;
```

Using boolean expressions inside the aggregation function as done here is called conditional aggregation.

The above query doesn't return detail_ids though that occur in files, but not in errors. If you need them, you can outer join above result to the files table.

Comment: this is a nice solution, however how do I eliminate the orphaned records in the errors table (row 8,9)? I need a results set with just the detail_ids from the files table.

Comment: `where detail_id in (select detail_id from files)` or joining above query to the files table as already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @Thorsten Kettner, you were very helpful in answering my question. Unfortunately, I can't vote yet as my reputation is only 11. Thanks again!

Comment: Surely `exists` (which might short circuit at the first record) would be faster than a count (which has to count all matching rows)?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Your are right, `EXISTS` is often faster. Here the query would have to run five `EXISTS` subqueries for every detail_id, though, while my query will just run once through the errors table. The key point is whether there exist only about those five different error codes or rather five thousand. With loads of codes we'd wish for a quick lookup via an index, with just five codes we would rather just read the table sequentially. If there even isn't an index on errors(detail_id), the lookups would become very slow. So, it all depends. :-)

Comment: You're exactly right - it depends, usually on stuff not provided in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, I think you should have an index:

```
create index error_det_id_i on errors(detail_id);
```

This should improve performance in any case.

```
select
  detail_id, 
  sum(case
    when error_code=400 then 1
    else 0
  end) cnt_err_400,
  sum(case
    when error_code=400 then 1
    else 0
  end) cnt_err_405,
  sum(case
    when error_code=400 then 1
    else 0
  end) cnt_err_410
from files f
left join errors e on f.detail_id=e.detail_id
group by detail_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, could just PIVOT errors table:

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM    ( Select  ID, DETAIL_ID, ERR_CODE
          From    errors)
        PIVOT ( Count(DETAIL_ID) "ERROR" For ERR_CODE IN(392, 400, 401, 405, 410) )
ORDER BY ID
```

... which with this sample data:

```sql
WITH
    errors AS
        (
            Select  1 "ID",  2 "DETAIL_ID", 400 "ERR_CODE", 'Bad format'    "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select  2 "ID",  3 "DETAIL_ID", 405 "ERR_CODE", 'Too long'      "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select  3 "ID",  3 "DETAIL_ID", 392 "ERR_CODE", 'Bad namme'     "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select  4 "ID",  5 "DETAIL_ID", 410 "ERR_CODE", 'Wrong filetype' "ERR_DESC" From Dual Union All
            Select  5 "ID",  6 "DETAIL_ID", 400 "ERR_CODE", 'Bad format'    "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select  6 "ID",  6 "DETAIL_ID", 392 "ERR_CODE", 'Bad name'      "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select  7 "ID",  8 "DETAIL_ID", 392 "ERR_CODE", 'Bad name'      "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select  8 "ID", 12 "DETAIL_ID", 400 "ERR_CODE", 'Bad format'    "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select  9 "ID", 13 "DETAIL_ID", 405 "ERR_CODE", 'Too long'      "ERR_DESC"  From Dual Union All
            Select 10 "ID",  1 "DETAIL_ID", 401 "ERR_CODE", 'Corrupted'     "ERR_DESC"  From Dual 
        )
```

... results as:

```sql
        ID  392_ERROR  400_ERROR  401_ERROR  405_ERROR  410_ERROR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0          1          0          0          0 
         2          0          0          0          1          0 
         3          1          0          0          0          0 
         4          0          0          0          0          1 
         5          0          1          0          0          0 
         6          1          0          0          0          0 
         7          1          0          0          0          0 
         8          0          1          0          0          0 
         9          0          0          0          1          0 
        10          0          0          1          0          0
```